# Yii2: save checkbox false as NULL

Tags: checkbox, yii2, active-form

In Yii2 I have `ActiveForm` with checkbox field. In mysql database it is `tinyint(1)` column that can be `NULL`.

I need unchecked checkbox (`false` value) to be saved as `NULL` in database. Currently when checkbox is unchecked, it is saved as `(int) 0`.

What is the proper way to save `false` value as `NULL`?

Here is the model:

```
class ProductToProductCategory extends ActiveRecord {

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['product_category_id', 'required'],
            ['product_category_id', 'integer'],
            ['is_main', 'boolean'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<?= $form->field($model, "is_main")->checkbox() ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['product_category_id', 'required'],
        ['product_category_id', 'integer'],
        ['is_main', 'boolean'],
        ['is_main', 'filter', function ($value) {
            // return value you need
            return $value ?: null;
        }, 'skipOnError' => true],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never tried it but you should be able to do it implementing the beforeSave method of the saved model.

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (!parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        return false;
    }

    if( $this->scenario == "strangeNullScenario" ) {
        if( empty( $this->FIELD ) ) {
            $this->FIELD = null;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I am aware of `beforeSave()`, but I am not sure if it the proper way of doing this... `beforeSave` acts globally, but I would want to limit this behaviour to particular scenario, not spreading it over the whole project.

Comment: You should check in which scenario you are saving then in the beforeSave. Updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just pass uncheck option

```
<?= $form->field($model, "is_main")->checkbox(['uncheck' => null]) ?>
```

Comment: 'uncheck' => '' would be correct